# The argument type 'Set<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, String>'

Tags: flutter, jwt, auth0, flutter-http

I'm trying to create an user authentication system using Auth0 in my Flutter app. The Auth0 REST documentation gave an example of cURL but I didn't find any flutter package which does the job of cURL. So, I used `http`.
Here's the code:

```
  Future<String> getToken(String userId) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://my-auth0-subdomain.auth0.com/oauth/token'),  // I used my real subdomain
      body: jsonEncode({
        'grant_type=client_credentials',
        'client_id=my_project_client_id',  // I used my real client id
        'client_secret=my_project_client_secret',  // I used my real client secret
        'audience=https://my-auth0-subdomain.auth0.com/api/v2/'  // I used my real subdomain
      }),
      headers: {
        'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
    );
    final token = jsonDecode(response.body)["access_token"];

    return token;
  }
```

This gives me an error that `The argument type 'Set<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, String>'.` on line 10 (`headers: {...}`). 
I can resolve this error by using `headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},`.
But this then gives the error from Auth0 `{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Unauthorized"}`. The API is set up properly, because on running

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://my-auth0-subdomain.auth0.com/oauth/token' \
  --header "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  --data grant_type=client_credentials \
  --data 'client_id=my_project_client_id' \
  --data client_secret=my_project_client_secret \
  --data 'audience=https://my-auth0-subdomain.auth0.com/api/v2/'
```

it returns a `"access_token"`, `"scope"`, `"expires_in"` and `"token_type"`.
Please help. It's very important.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Instead of `'grant_type=client_credentials'` use `'grant_type':'client_credentials'`. Every value you should change like that

Comment: @MidhunMP But if I do that, then the response is ```{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Unauthorized"}```. I think that Auth0 accepts only ```"content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"``` and not ```"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"```.

Comment: Why are you sending body as jsonEncode and setting header content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded and not application/json

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks for the suggestion! I mixed your suggestion with my code and it worked! Don't know how  but it works

Comment: @Dev Auth0 said that it strictly wants application/x-www-form-urlencoded and that it won't accept any other header type

Comment: then why not send data as form encode instead of jsonencoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send data as url encoded using :

```
Map<String, String> myBody= {

'grant_type' : 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' : 'my_project_client_id',  // I used my real client id
        'client_secret' : 'my_project_client_secret',  // I used my real client secret
        'audience ' : 'https://my-auth0-subdomain.auth0.com/api/v2/'  // I used my real subdomain     
};

Future<String> getToken(String userId) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://my-auth0-subdomain.auth0.com/oauth/token'),  // I used my real subdomain
      body: myBody,
      headers: {
        'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
    );
    final token = jsonDecode(response.body)["access_token"];

    return token;
  }
```